# Get columns names only from multiple tables by a join query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM 

fbr.*, c.sample, ci.dob, ci.country, ci.sex 

FROM `finalBloodReport` fbr ,`clients` c, `client_info` ci  

 WHERE fbr.sampleSerialNo = (CONCAT(c.resellerSerialId,'-',c.kitSerialNo) ) 

AND c.client_id = ci.id";
```

**This is my query it works fine and gives the desired output,But since i am showing data in table i also want to get columns name only for this query to show them as table header .**

**I tried Something like this , but result is null.**

```
 $sql = "SHOW COLUMNS

    fbr.*, c.sample, ci.dob, ci.country, ci.sex 

    FROM `finalBloodReport` fbr ,`clients` c, `client_info` ci  

     WHERE fbr.sampleSerialNo = (CONCAT(c.resellerSerialId,'-',c.kitSerialNo) ) 

    AND c.client_id = ci.id";
```

Can anyone help ? I am not so good with mysql ; (

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve column information after query is executed. This can be done by using `mysqli_fetch_field()`

You code should look like following

```
$result = mysqli_query($sql);

while($field = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {
    print $field->name . "\t";
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result) {
    print_r($row);
}
```